# zoom and focus to x and y cordinates of an image

Tags: html, css, transform, zooming, scale

Is it possible to zoom to a point if the x and y coordinates are known?
I have an image and a point in that image whose coordinates and coordinates are known.And these coordinates are dynamic. Means it can be changed accordingly. on a mouse click event Am trying to zoom to that specific point.
For zooming, the below code is enough. Any help or reference links are appreciated.

```
.image img {

 -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
 -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
 transition: all 1s ease;

 }


.imgclickedtop{


 -moz-transform:scale(3) !important; /* Firefox */
 -ms-transform:scale(3) !important; /* IE 9 */
 -o-transform:scale(3) !important; /* Opera */
  transform:scale(3) !important;
```

}

Comment: That's possible if you use [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: for that we should know the position of the coordinates. right? How we say that whether the cordinate is in center or top or left?

Answer (score 0):

use

```css
transform-origin: x-axis y-axis;
```

Where the axis are in **%** or in any **length** unit or one of **left|right|center** for x and **top|bottom|center** for y.

The default value for both x and y is 50%, which means the default origin is at the center 0% 0% means "left top" while 100% 100% means "right bottom"

Comment: Use vendor prefix for old browser support

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute('zoom-img')) {
    const px = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, e.layerX / e.target.clientWidth));
    const py = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, e.layerY / e.target.clientHeight));
    e.target.style.setProperty('--zoom-center-x', px * 100);
    e.target.style.setProperty('--zoom-center-y', py * 100);
  }
})
```

```css
[zoom-img] {
  --zoom-factor: 1;
  --zoom-center-x: 50;
  --zoom-center-y: 50;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[zoom-img] img {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(calc(var(--zoom-factor, 1)));
          transform: scale(calc(var(--zoom-factor, 1)));
  -webkit-transform-origin: calc(1% * var(--zoom-center-x, 50)) calc(1% * var(--zoom-center-y, 50));
          transform-origin: calc(1% * var(--zoom-center-x, 50)) calc(1% * var(--zoom-center-y, 50));
}
```

```html
1 &times;
<div zoom-img style="--zoom-factor: 1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1960/1080" alt="">
</div>
2 &times;
<div zoom-img style="--zoom-factor: 2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1960/1080" alt="">
</div>
10 &times;
<div zoom-img style="--zoom-factor: 10">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1960/1080" alt="">
</div>
```